# jquery gallery and HTML element to hold the information

Tags: jquery, html, image-gallery

I'm trying to build just another gallery. There is lots of them but I didn't find anyone that actually supported my need, and beside I like to learn.

Basically I want the first picture in my gallery displayed (in full size). When I press the navigation arrow (Let's say it's just below the image) I want the next picture to show. Nothing strange with that.

The gallery should allow the image, an alt-text set and a caption.

However I want the option to NOT pre load the images that has not yet been displayed. Therefore it looks like I cannot use the  tag witch otherwise would support all my needs. Would it be bad practice to substitute the -tag with the following:

```
<a href="srcforpic.jpg" title="alt text">Caption goes here</a>
```

The Jquery would then parse this and create some kind of freaky object that can be used to construct an img-tag only when the that image is requested. (and stores it of course)

Pros & cons?

Comment: so did u try adding "#" ? did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with what you want few months (years?) ago. Take a look [here](http://iamntz.com/experiments/dSlide/).
Is just a proof of concept, but i guess is still a good start.

Answer (score 0):

well, if I were you, instead if doing that , I'd just add a "#" to all image SRCs excpet for the one that's being shown, and once the person move to next image, remove # from the src of that image, it's alot simpler and speedier than your solution

Comment: yeah it is, that's a typical solution for this kind of scenarios, changing the tag name has a hell lot of coding for the same result